# Access class[x] within another class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So lets say i have a div setup like this:

```
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score></div>
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score>
    <div class="compare"><div>
</div>
```

I am using hopscotch tour which popups the tour at the element target. To access the 4th div i would do this

```
$('.score')[3]
```

But how would i access the compare class within that 4th class assuming their could be other compare classes used so i specifically want to target the compare class within the 4th score element.

i guess im trying to do something like this but i have no idea of the correct format and if i knew the correct search terms to search on google i would probably find it but i dont know the correct term im looking for.

Some bad attempts are:

```
$('.score')[3].compare; 
$('.score[3] > compare');
$('.score > compare')[3];
$('.score').eq(3).compare;
```

And for bonus points what about the other way around. If i had:

```
<div class="score">
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
<div>
```

What if i wanted to access the 4th element of compare inside the score class

Comment: `$('.score .compare:nth-child(4)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hvaf2uxb/2/),
For your case 1

```
<div id='case1'>
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score">
    <div class="compare">test<div>
</div>
</div>


var $target = $('#case1');
var text = $('#case1').find('div.score:eq(3) > div.compare').text();
alert(text);
```

For case 2

```
<div id='case2'>
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"><div>
<div class="score">
    <div class="compare">test1</div>
    <div class="compare">test2</div>
    <div class="compare">test3</div>
    <div class="compare">test4</div>
</div>
</div>

var $target = $('#case2');
var  text = $('#case2').find('div.score:eq(3) > div.compare:eq(3)').text();
alert(text);
```

Hope it work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.score').children().eq(3).hasClass('compare');
```

This will return true/false if fourth element has 'companre' class

Enjoy!